# solving scoping issure in a custom function to extract data from `htest` object

Tags: r, evaluation, scoping

I am struggling with some scoping issues where I am trying to extract dataframe.

Here is a **portion** of a larger custom function to extract data from McNemar's test and other `htest` objects:

```r
get_data <- function(x, ...) {
  data_name <- unlist(strsplit(x$data.name, " (and|by) "))
  data_call <- lapply(data_name, str2lang)
  columns <- lapply(data_call, eval)
  as.table(columns[[1]])
}
```

## using outside function environment

The function works as expected:

```r
# data
Performance <-
  matrix(c(794, 86, 150, 570),
    nrow = 2,
    dimnames = list(
      "1st Survey" = c("Approve", "Disapprove"),
      "2nd Survey" = c("Approve", "Disapprove")
    )
  )

# using the function
mod <- stats::mcnemar.test(Performance)
get_data(mod) # it works!

#>             2nd Survey
#> 1st Survey   Approve Disapprove
#>   Approve        794        150
#>   Disapprove      86        570
```

## using inside function environment

Doesn't work unfortunately

```r
foo <- function(data) {
  mod <- stats::mcnemar.test(data)
  print(mod) # making sure data is being read internally
  
  get_data(mod) # it doesn't work :(
}

foo(Performance)
#> 
#>  McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  data
#> McNemar's chi-squared = 16.818, df = 1, p-value = 4.115e-05
#> Error in as.table.default(columns[[1]]): cannot coerce to a table
```

Is there any way to make this work, either by changing the custom function to extract data (`get_data`) or by modifying the function where it is called (`foo`)?

Comment: Wouldn't `get` work for you? `get_data <- function(x, ...) {
  data_name <- unlist(strsplit(x$data.name, " (and|by) ")); get(data_name, envir = parent.frame())};
 foo(Performance)#`

Comment: `print(data_name)` returns `"data"`. Then `str2lang` coerces this character string to a language object, then `eval` evaluates it, returning the function `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RuiBarradas mentioned in the comments, the `mcnemar.test` is creating the `list` element 'data.name' as the input `data` instead of the value stored in it.  It can be changed after applying the test

```
get_data <- function(x, ...) {
   data_name <- unlist(strsplit(x$data.name, " (and|by) "))
   data_call <- lapply(data_name, str2lang)
   columns <- lapply(data_call, eval)
   as.table(columns[[1]])
   
   
 }
 
 
foo <- function(data) {
   
   mod <- stats::mcnemar.test(data)
   mod$data.name <- deparse(substitute(data))
   print(mod) # making sure data is being read internally
  
   get_data(mod) # it doesn't work :(
 }

foo(Performance)
#   McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

#data:  Performance
#McNemar's chi-squared = 16.818, df = 1, p-value = 4.115e-05

#            2nd Survey
#1st Survey   Approve Disapprove
#  Approve        794        150
#  Disapprove      86        570
```

---

Or use `get`

```
get_data <- function(x, ...) { 
    data_name <- unlist(strsplit(x$data.name, " (and|by) "))
    as.table(get(data_name, envir = parent.frame()))
    }
foo(Performance)
#McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

#data:  Performance
#McNemar's chi-squared = 16.818, df = 1, p-value = 4.115e-05

#            2nd Survey
#1st Survey   Approve Disapprove
#  Approve        794        150
#  Disapprove      86        570
```

Comment: Do you think the solution using `deparse` won't work if the function `foo` lies inside a package? Because it doesn't seem to work in that context, but I need to toy around with it a bit more.

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil I haven't test it within a package?  Would the `get` work if the correct `envir` is specified

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will play around with different environments and see if it works.